# show value on ngx-charts heat map

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am working with [ngx charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@swimlane/ngx-charts) to show the data in `Heat Map`. Its working fine without any issues.

[Working Example | Heat Map](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-heat-map)

But I want to show the each grid values instead of showing it on `mouse hover`. Is there any way to do that?

I checked the `ngx-charts` documentaion also but no luck.

[ngx-charts documntation](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/heat-map-chart#inputs)

Answer (score 0):

The heatmap component doesn't support that. You could customize the templates used to render the heatmap, but customizing ngx-charts is not for the faint of heart:

https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/custom-charts

Alternatively, you might be able to create a similar chart with the treemap, if each value were the same for instance:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-tree-map-chart?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts